# Modify/move selected objects and show an xyz coordinates popup to edit as well.,Show a pop-up to modify xyz coordinates for an object to be moved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity, so I wonder if there's some how a way, I could do allow the user running my program/game to select a single/multiple objects and move them, in addition to having a pop-up of xyz coordinates shown incase he wanted to use it as well. I know the first part could be done easily in unity, but what I am not sure it can be done, or how to do it even is the pop-up with the xyz coordinate of the actual selected objects to modify. Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

I tried looking for tutorial to do what I am looking for, but I never found any and I will still search for more. I am expecting any help to do what I have mentioned above.

Comment: try raycasting mouse position in 3d world and then update your object position to that raycast hit.

Comment: You’ll need to look up ways to do it in several parts. For example, to get the coordinates of the object is easy (the object’s transform.position.x etc.), but displaying them will require you to use a TextMeshPro object or similar. For selecting and moving the objects you’ll need to think about how you’d like that to be controlled and then look for ways to achieve each part of that. If you get stuck you’ll probably still have learned enough by then to be able to post a more specific question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.